# Routing for an API with subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have written a simple API but something feels wrong about the routes and the APIs. Its my first time am writing an API and just a few months writing ROR code. Take a look at the code below and help me straighten it!!

I wish the API to respond to requests like https://api.xxxxx.com/v1/xml?username=u_name&password=passwd& to=xxxxx&from=xxxx&message=text

The subdomain does not seem to be working either;

Routes

```
  namespace :api, :path => "", constraints: {subdomain: 'api'} do
namespace :v1  do
  namespace :json, defaults: {format: :json} do
    resources :messages
    resources :balance
  end

  namespace :xml, defaults: {format: :xml} do
    resources :messages
    resources :balance
  end

end

end
```

These are the controllers for the json API

Messages Controller:

```
class Api::V1::Json::MessagesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate


def show

end

def create
    @user = current_user
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    if @message.save
      MessageWorker.perform_async(@message.id, lists, current_user.id)
      render json: {status: "success", to: @message.count, from: @message.from, 
                    balance: @user.balance, message: @message.message}, 
                    time: @message.created_at} 
    else
       render status: 400 
    end
end


def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username,password|
      resource = User.find_by_email(username)
      if resource.valid_password?(password)
        sign_in :user, resource
      end
    end
end

end
```

Balance Controller:

```
class Api::V1::Json::BalanceController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate


def show
    @balance = current_user.balance
    render json: {user: current_user.name.titleize, balance: "#{current_user.currency}: #{@balance}"}

end

def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username,password|
      resource = User.find_by_email(username)
      if resource.valid_password?(password)
        sign_in :user, resource
      end
    end
end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
constraints subdomain: 'api' do
  scope module: :api do
    namespace :v1 do
```

You'd rather not namespace json or xml, it makes no sense: the same controllers should handle both request, just a matter of format.
Rails makes it really easy with `respond_to`